# Meteor OAuth is taking a long time over LTE / 4g / 3g

Tags: oauth, meteor

I recently released LinkedIn OAuth on my Meteor mobile [app](http://blonk.co). I'm running into long 12-20sec login times on LTE/4G/3G. On wifi, login happens around 1 second.

Some users are reporting that the `loggingIn` spinner spins for 10 seconds and then stops, but I can't replicate that on my phone.

Has anyone had issues with this before? Any ideas on how I can speed this up?

Comment: If you ever find a reproduction, please, file an issue on GitHub. Several theories: your mongodb server is far away from Meteor server and Meteor server is far away from LinkedIn server and Client is far away from everything => big latencies. Or maybe the localStorage is super slow on the phone of your client. Or you get a lot of load on your server.

Comment: Also publish Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration for a decent speedup with something like FastRender. (The logic behind this is a lot of 3G/LTE/2G networks use a proxy that stops websockets in an attempt to boost performance and it takes a bit of time to actually connect to to the backend). If you send the oAuth service data to the client it could be faster

Comment: @imslavko I've seen it happen to me because my isp uses byte mobile, Meteor attempts to connect with websockets then fails, then tries again with long polling and in all it takes a bit of time.

Comment: @Akshat oh wow thanks! I've disabled websockets on the server, i'll try FastRender sometime tonight!

Comment: @Akshat Do you happen to know the exact syntax for the publication? Is it just `Meteor.publish('Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference here's how you can publish it with fast render:

```
// serverside
Meteor.publish("loginConfig", function(){
  return Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.find();
});



// client route

this.route('home', { 
  path: '/', fastRender: true,
  waitOn: function(){
    return Meteor.subscribe('loginConfig');
  }
});
```